# entity framework, mysql and IQueryable

Tags: mysql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I'm using Entity Framework with MySQL and I can't get the right query execution. I'm trying to have one point for accessing a type of object. I.e. Address.
This is what I have on repository.

```
public IQueryable<Address> GetAddresses()
        {
            return from a in DBContext.addresses
                   select new Address
                   {
                       Id = a.instance,
                       City = a.city,
                       Country = a.country,
                       Owner = a.owner,
                       PostalCode = a.postcode,
                       Street = a.street
                   };

        }
```

On Service Layer I'm adding a predicate that would be added to IQueryable object and execute the query

```
public Data.Address GetAddress(Func<Data.Address, bool> predicate)
        {
            List<Data.Address> items = referenceDataRepository.GetAddresses().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();

return items;
        }
```

a predicate would be ( x => x.Owner = 233)
When checking the MySQL log I see that query being executed DOES NOT include a where clause and it seems that the predicate is applied after returning all the addresses, which is very expensive.

Am I missing something in regard of IQueryable and how it's executed.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you project into an instance of `Address`? Can't you simply use `return from a in DBContext.addresses select a;` in your `GetAddresses` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you defined predicate as `Func<Data.Address, bool>` you must define it as expression: `Expression<Func<Data.Address, bool>>`. `Func` converts your `Where` part to linq to objects.